# How to remove extra space of a textarea inside a div in chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, textarea

I have a textarea that aligns perfectly to the left on firefox, but on chrome, a little space is added. I don't know why it's there, but I tried a lot of things to get rid of the space but just can't.
[image]
Chrome pushes the textarea like 2 pixels to the right. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or is there a way to align it on chrome?

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testdiv.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="outermostshell">    
    <div class="textareashell">
            <textarea name="status" rows="2" cols="30"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.outermostshell
    {
        position:fixed;
        width:300px;
        height:600px;
        background-color:red;

    }

.textareashell
    {
        position:relative;
        top:10px;
        padding:0;
        border:0;
        left:0px;
                margin:0px;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some browsers (including Chrome) have a default margin for form elements. Just set the margin to zero:

```
.textareashell textarea { margin: 0; }
```

Comment: I would suggest you use `textarea {margin:0;}` (without the .textareashell class), so these would be global changes, thus requiring extra markup on your html.

Comment: @Marcello: It doesn't need any extra markup as the OP already has it. Applying such a setting to all textareas may or may not be preferable in different situations.

Comment: @Guffa: Actually, I would even go a step further and do `input[type="text"], textarea {margin:0;}`, once they are often styled the same way. Just to clarify, that is a matter of personal preference, because you had already provided the answer to @r1nzler's question. :-)

Comment: You can also use Normalize.css which brings consistency to how browsers render default elements: http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-normalize-css/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use padding-left: 2px;